# Symfony Validation Error: Fields Meet Requirements but Still Getting "NotBlank" and "NotNull" Errors

Tags: php, symfony, postman

I'm working on a Symfony project where I have a directorDetails class and  i want to deserialize an array data into each fields in the direcctorDetails class. Currently,The specific problem lies in the deserializing the array data that I'm trying to send into an array objects and map it to the fields inside the directorDetails class.
my question now is How to deserialize the  array data and map it into each fields in my directorDetails class.
The step i followed is shown in the code below which give an error as follows;

```
object(App\Document\DirectorDetails)#540 (1) {
    [
        "id":"App\Document\DirectorDetails":private
    ]=>
  NULL
  [
        "fullName":"App\Document\DirectorDetails":private
    ]=>
  uninitialized(string)
  [
        "phoneNumber":"App\Document\DirectorDetails":private
    ]=>
  uninitialized(string)
  [
        "Email":"App\Document\DirectorDetails":private
    ]=>
  uninitialized(string)
  [
        "ResidentialAddress":"App\Document\DirectorDetails":private
    ]=>
  uninitialized(string)
  [
        "BVN":"App\Document\DirectorDetails":private
    ]=>
  uninitialized(string)
}
{
    "type": "https://symfony.com/errors/validation",
    "title": "Validation Failed",
    "detail": "fullName: This value should not be blank.\nphoneNumber: This value should not be blank.\nEmail: This value should not be blank.\nResidentialAddress: This value should not be blank.\nBVN: This value should not be blank.",
    "violations": [
        {
            "propertyPath": "fullName",
            "title": "This value should not be blank.",
            "parameters": {
                "{{ value }}": "null"
            },
            "type": "urn:uuid:c1051bb4-d103-4f74-8988-acbcafc7fdc3"
        },
        {
            "propertyPath": "phoneNumber",
            "title": "This value should not be blank.",
            "parameters": {
                "{{ value }}": "null"
            },
            "type": "urn:uuid:c1051bb4-d103-4f74-8988-acbcafc7fdc3"
        },
        {
            "propertyPath": "Email",
            "title": "This value should not be blank.",
            "parameters": {
                "{{ value }}": "null"
            },
            "type": "urn:uuid:c1051bb4-d103-4f74-8988-acbcafc7fdc3"
        },
        {
            "propertyPath": "ResidentialAddress",
            "title": "This value should not be blank.",
            "parameters": {
                "{{ value }}": "null"
            },
            "type": "urn:uuid:c1051bb4-d103-4f74-8988-acbcafc7fdc3"
        },
        {
            "propertyPath": "BVN",
            "title": "This value should not be blank.",
            "parameters": {
                "{{ value }}": "null"
            },
            "type": "urn:uuid:c1051bb4-d103-4f74-8988-acbcafc7fdc3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's my directorDetails class

```
 #[ODM\Document(repositoryClass:DirectorDetailsRepository::class)]
class DirectorDetails
{

   
    #[ODM\Id(strategy: "UUID")]
    private ?string $id = null;

    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[ODM\Field(type: "string")]
    private string $fullName;

    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[ODM\Field(type: "string")]
    private string $phoneNumber;

    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\Email(message: "The email '{{ value }}' is not a valid email address.")]
    #[ODM\Field(type: "string")]
    private string $Email;

    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[ODM\Field(type: "string")]
    private string $ResidentialAddress;

    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[ODM\Field(type: "string")]
    private string $BVN;

    






    public function getId(): ?string
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFullName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->fullName;
    }


    public function setFullName(string $fullName): static
    {
        $this->fullName = $fullName;
        return $this;
    }


    public function getPhoneNumber(): ?string
    {
        return $this->phoneNumber;
    }

    public function setPhoneNumber(string $phoneNumber): static
    {
        $this->phoneNumber = $phoneNumber;
        return $this;
    }


    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $Email): static
    {
        $this->Email = $Email;
        return $this;
    }


    public function getResidentialAddress(): ?string
    {
        return $this->ResidentialAddress;
    }

    public function setResidentialAddress(string $ResidentialAddress): static
    {
        $this->ResidentialAddress = $ResidentialAddress;
        return $this;
    }


    public function getBVN(): ?string
    {
        return $this->BVN;
    }

    public function setBVN(string  $BVN): static
    {
        $this->BVN = $BVN;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Here is my controller class

```
#[Route('/companyDetails/{id}/directorDetails', name: 'app_company_director_create', methods: ['POST'])]
                    public function createDirectorDetails(CompanyDetailsRepository $repo, SerializerInterface $serializer, ValidatorInterface $validator, CompanyDetails $companyDetails, Request $request): JsonResponse
            
                {
                    var_dump($request->getContent());
                    $directorDetails = $serializer->deserialize($request->
          getContent(), DirectorDetails::class, 'json');
                    $companyDetails->addDirectorDetail($directorDetails);
                    var_dump($directorDetails);
            
            
                    $errors = $validator->validate($directorDetails);
                    if (count($errors) > 0) {
                        return $this->json($errors, 422);
                    }
            
                    $repo->save($companyDetails, true);
            
                    return $this->json($directorDetails, 201);
                }
    

Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Do you have the code where you process the data you send? Have you tried dumping the objects once built to see if the values are properly populated?

Comment: [
    "fullName":"App\Document\DirectorDetails":private
]=>
  uninitialized(string)
  [
    "phoneNumber":"App\Document\DirectorDetails":private
]=>
  uninitialized(string)
  [
    "Email":"App\Document\DirectorDetails":private
]=>
  uninitialized(string)
  [
    "ResidentialAddress":"App\Document\DirectorDetails":private
]=>
  uninitialized(string)
  [
    "BVN":"App\Document\DirectorDetails":private
]=>
  uninitialized(string)
}
here's the response i got when i added var_dump in my controller to see how the values are populated

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Sounds like populating the data does not work - can you share the code involved?

Comment: What does dumping the request content yield? Why not start any debugger (like XDebug) to properly inspect where this is going wrong? Are you sure that Postman itself is to blame?

Comment: Are you passing a JSON as an array of objects and trying to deserialize it in a single object instead of an array of objects?

Comment: I have a directorDetails class, which I've embedded as an array capable of accepting multiple objects within another class named companyDetails. Currently,  The specific problem lies in the deserializing the array data that I'm trying to send into an array objects and map it to the fields inside the directorDetails class. I've documented the steps I followed in the provided code.

Comment: my question now is How to deserialize an array objects data and map it into a symfony fields in a symfony class

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. How does the request's content look like?